# How to set same meta data across collections?

Tags: docpad

Am trying to set a product category on different collections but only the last collection defined in docpad.coffee actually sets it when trying it like so

```
firstCollection: ->
    @getCollection("html").findAllLive().on "add", (model) ->
        model.setMeta({category: 'first'})
secondCollection: ->
    @getCollection("html").findAllLive().on "add", (model) ->
        model.setMeta({category: 'second'})
```

`document.category`will be 'second' for all documents of each collection.

How to set the same meta data individually per doc in a collection?

Comment: How else would I separate the same doc for different categories AND know the category it will render for with the current request to build up a matching navigation etc.?

Comment: So there is absolutely no option to have the very same doc show up in multiple collections but with different (meta)data for each?

Answer (score 2):

What problem are you trying to solve? Because your approach is not going to work.  If you share what you're trying to do, we may be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Your current approach won't work because you are setting a metadata property named "category" that is a string.  That metadata property lives on the *documents* in the collection and not on the *collection* itself.

Both collections are pointing at the same set of documents. Each individual document can only have a single value for that property.  It can't be both 'first' and 'second'.  The last one to set it wins, and in this case, the event that sets it to 'second' is happening last and so all of the documents have 'second' as the value for that metadata property.

Comment: Great explanation. If you are wanting to perhaps rename `category` to `categories` and make it an array, you could try: `(model.attributes.categories ?= []).push('first')` instead of the setMeta

Comment: **rrrr why can't the stackoverflowers just make a standard return work in these edit fields?!**

I was hoping for DocPad to allow for documents being shared across categories / products instead of having to continue w/ replicated double contents as with Jekyll and Github pages before.

@balupton - that said your snippet would still reference the very same doc and not the collection - so it won't work either :/

Isn't there any way to set individual attributes to the set up collection?

Comment: If I can ask, what problem are you trying to solve?  I mean what is the specific scenario where you're trying to reuse content but need different meta data?  There may be an alternative approach we could suggest if we knew what your use case was...

Comment: If I want the same document to show up in different product categories from a single navigation partial and persist the category when navigating what else would work?

Comment: P.P.S. ... isn't there any way to persist extra attributes per collection and use such for navigation or else within partials?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found a better way to do this: `model.setMetaDefaults({foo:'bar'})`

For example, to create a blog collection with a default `cssClass` of `post`:

```
collections: {
  blog: function() {
    return this.getCollection("documents")
      .findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:'blog'}, [{filename:-1}])
      .on("add", function (model) {
        model.setMetaDefaults({'cssClass': 'post'})
      });
  }
},
```

This would go in your `docpad.coffee` file or, in my case, `docpad.js`.

See a working example with full context at https://github.com/nfriedly/nfriedly.com/blob/master/docpad.js#L72 (collection is called "techblog", starts around like 72).

Comment: Mh, don't get this working. Can you extend your example to show a second collection setting the same meta properties with different, collection-specific data per collection?

Comment: Where in docpad is your sample meant to go?

Comment: The code goes in your `docpad.coffee` or docpad.js` file, but I just re-wrote the answer with a better solution and a link to a full example. Cheers :)

Comment: Ah, seems like we misunderstood each other :/ - I was and am looking for a possibility to set the same property (e.g. 'category') for all documents across collections but set that to a collection specific value (e.g. 'first'). With `setMetaDefaults`you "will only set the Meta Data Model attributes that haven't already been set to something."; https://docpad.org/docs/meta-data. So that gets us back to Erv's answer then.

Comment: Oh... I just re-read your question, and my answer doesn't really apply. So yea, I think Erv is correct here. Sorry about the mixup.